# Swift iOS 9 NSURLErrorDomain Error -1004

Tags: ios, swift2, ios9, alamofire

I'm using Swift 2 and Alamofire with both iOS 9 and iOS 8. In iOS 8 all my requests to my API work fine. In iOS 9 they immediately fail with a -1004 NSURLErrorDomain with the message "Could not connect to the server.". I read about Apple's change with App Transport Security and already added the entry to my Plist to disable it and allow insecure connections.

I'm at a loss as to the reason for this error...any help would be great!

Comment: Do you allow it to true?

Comment: @BankerMittal: Yes, I have changed my plist to allow all insecure connections. It should be working. It worked with the first release of iOS9, but one of the bug updates broke it.

Comment: new release of ios 9  - ios 9.1 has come recently .please do update and check it.

Comment: It does not work in iOS 9.1 on the simulators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After messing around with a ton of different keys and values to make it work, I finally have come up with this to make it function in iOS9.1:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>mydomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

After I added the last one `NSRequiresCertificateTransparency` and set that to false it worked, so that's probably the most important one.