# iOS api call to local RESTful Django fails

Tags: ios, django, swift, django-rest-framework, swifty-json

Hi all first time posting a question. Long time reaping the benefits of other questions so I'd like to preface this with a thank you to everyone who answers questions on here.

Onto my question. So I've set up a local Django server that returns a JSON object to my browser properly. I've also set up an API querying scheme in IOS using swift that work properly with the tutorials HTTP server. However when I try to call my own local server my data and response objects are nill

My Django view.py and url.py files

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from snippets.models import Snippet
from django.http import Http404
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer

class SnippetList(APIView):
    """
    List all snippets, or create a new snippet.
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        snippets = Snippet.objects.all()
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippets, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class SnippetDetail(APIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update or delete a snippet instance.
    """
    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = SnippetSerializer(snippet, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        snippet = self.get_object(pk)
        snippet.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

My iOS API file

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

typealias ServiceResponse = (JSON, NSError?) -> Void

class RestApiManager: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = RestApiManager()

let baseURL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/?format=json"

func getRandomUser(onCompletion: (JSON) -> Void) {
    let route = baseURL
    makeHTTPGetRequest(route, onCompletion: { json, err in
        onCompletion(json as JSON)
    })
}

func makeHTTPGetRequest(path: String, onCompletion: ServiceResponse) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        print(data)
        print(response)
        print(error)
        print("list")
        let json:JSON = JSON(data: data!)
        onCompletion(json, error)
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

My View controller that adds table rows dynamically

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
import SwiftyJSON

class TableMenu: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var tableView:UITableView?
    var items = NSMutableArray()

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let frame:CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height-100)
    self.tableView = UITableView(frame: frame)
    self.tableView?.dataSource = self
    self.tableView?.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView!)

    let btn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 25, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50))
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
    btn.setTitle("Add new Dummy", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(TableMenu.addDummyData), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(btn)
    }




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CELL") as UITableViewCell!

    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "CELL")
    }

    let user:JSON =  JSON(self.items[indexPath.row])

    print(user)
    //let picURL = user["picture"]["medium"].string
    //print(picURL)
    //let url = NSURL(string: picURL!)
    //let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    //print(user)
    cell!.textLabel?.text = user.string //user["username"].string
   // cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)

    return cell!
}
func addDummyData() {
    RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getRandomUser { json in
        let results = json.array
       for Json: JSON in results! {
        let user: AnyObject = Json["id"].string!
            print(user)
            self.items.addObject(user)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                self.tableView?.reloadData()
            })
        }
    }
}
    /*
     // MARK: - Navigation

     // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
     override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
     }
     */

}
```

The error I get when i print out the error object from dataTaskWithRequest method i get

```
Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x12dd99a50 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/?format=json, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/?format=json, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server.})
```

I looked on here for a while for an answer to this but everything is about authentification and I figured id start by getting the two communicating before I give users specific databases that require authentification to access

Thanks for your time.

Please critique my stack-overflow etiquette so my future questions are received positively.

Cheers y'all

Edit My info.plist looks as follows
[info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNDJ2.png)

Comment: Speaking as someone who has reviewed first posts in the past, this one is excellent.

Comment: However, it's also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/32936183/5276890. Please google stack overflow before asking. I found this after 5 minutes with the search for 'NSURLErrorDomain 1004'

Comment: Roy I forgot to mention that to get the tutorials api to work i had to allow arbitrary loads. I added a screenshot of my plist file in the new edited version of my question

Comment: Are you trying to do this on simulator or on your phone?

Comment: Im running it on my Ipad. I'm trying to keep it all on my local server which might have something to do with it? My browser loads the JSON object the same way it loads the tutorial's object though. I'm starting to think there might be a permissions thing in DJANGO but I haven't found anything and again it loads in the browswer just fine. When I started to add authentication modules to my Django code the browser couldn't load it anymore.

Comment: Did you use in the iPad code the right ip address? Are you tested your local server version in the iPad browser too? Which ip address did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Apple has disabled all unsecured HTTP traffic from iOS apps, as a part of App Transport Security. This helps in enforcing security best practices.

If you try to make HTTP requests with ATS enabled (using NSURLSession or libraries like AFNetworking), you’ll the error you are getting.

**Solution:-**

Open Info.plist, and add the following lines:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

**Caution:-**

Please keep in mind that above solution should be your last resort. You’d ideally want to enable HTTPS on your service, or next, whitelist domains on which you want HTTP and if none of this is possible, then use this approach

For more information refer this link:
http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2015/06/working-with-apples-application-transport-security/

Answer (score 0):

Gy pointed out I should use my computers IP address. After so reading about local servers I found that when I run a django server on my mac it can't be accessed from my iPad.

Therefore For me to get it to work i need to link the ipad to my mac by being on the same network and putting the IP address in the URL.

I havent gotten it working but I need to focus on the front end development at this time but for whatever travelers run upon this post this link should help.

[Access localhost on Mac from XCode? Phonegap communicating with Ajax to a local Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776412/access-localhost-on-mac-from-xcode-phonegap-communicating-with-ajax-to-a-local)

I will hopefully get it working in the future and update this answer.

Cheers