# image loading error with suffix '.Jpg'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I encountered an image loading error. Error messages were as follows:

> PAC Fetch failed with error [NSURLErrorDomain:-1004] []
>   nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error:
>   NSURLErrorDomain: -1004

Found that URLs of those images had an suffix `.Jpg` or other uncommon things, which correct loaded on Android.
I guess the problem is the wrong suffix, but not sure. I can't understand the meaning of those error msgs. Could anybody help me?

Comment: found the problem at last. It's about the server. It cannot support those pics' .webp format, which pics' urls have been transferred to, before downloading, by suffixing ".webp".

Answer (score 0):

kCFURLErrorCannotConnectToHost = -1004,

Maybe you have not SSL connection. Then your connection will be blocked by iOS for safety reasons. You need  [to add the host to the PLIST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936183/swift-ios-9-nsurlerrordomain-error-1004)

**EDIT:**
**Answered by OP** in comment section:

> found the problem at last. It's about the server. It cannot support
>   those pics' .webp format, which pics' urls have been transferred to,
>   before downloading, by suffixing ".webp

Comment: I need more information than "didnt work". Do you have SSL connection? if YES, update the question with example code on how you load the images and maybe an example URL of what you are trying to load

Comment: Sorry for all this long time..Found the problem with a workmate's help. Check comment please.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution for this question. It was a problem of HTML meta tag Content-Security-policy configuration. I have bypassed the policy using

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src data: gap: *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

and all services are working fine for me.